# Can't set elements height to its scrollHeight?

Tags: javascript, expand, contract

I can't for some reason make a smooth div, I'm trying to make it expand and contract when I click a button, but it doesn't work.

Javascript:

```
function expandContract(id) {
    var object = document.getElementById(id);
    if (object.style.height != "0px") {
        object.style.height = "0px";
    } else {
        object.style.height = object.scrollHeight;  
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='test' style='overflow:hidden;'>
Test pest fest.
</div>
<button onClick='expandContract("test");'>Expand/Contract</button>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DHWMk/)

I've also tried setting it do max-height, but still I can't get it to expand again. How would I do this without any javascript plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `+"px"`. You are required to set a unit (`em`, `px`, `%`, etc) when using `style.height`. Because `scrollHeight` gives you just a numeric value, you must append the units which are `px` in this case.

```
function expandContract(id) {
    var object = document.getElementById(id);
    if (object.style.height != "0px") {
        object.style.height = "0px";
    } else {
        object.style.height = object.scrollHeight+"px";  
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DHWMk/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work in Chrome, as is.
IE when I changed the 'overflow' to 'scroll'.